# Dealing with large result sets in SQL Server Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssas, olap, cubes

I have a Database that contains data about **articles**,**structures** and **manufacturers**. Meaning an article is linked to 1 manufacturer and to N structure-nodes (think as article-classification-nodes).

Querying articles using T-SQL with a lot of conditions is currently too slow to be usable for an e-shop, even with good hardware and properly indexed tables. (Should be below 1 sec).
Now I wonder if it would make sense to access this data through an OLAP Cube. I already developed one to get aggregations, like: *How many articles of manufacturer X exist below node Y **recursively**?*

These aggregations are pretty fast, now I wonder if it makes sense to also retrieve whole article-result sets through Cubes. Meaning: *Give me **every single** article ID of manufacturer X that exist below node Y recursively*. Because the result sets can be quite large, the query takes even longer..

Therefore my question, is there a way to deal with large result sets in SSAS, or is this totally the wrong direction I am taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely deal with large sets of data and make them perform decently in SSAS by leveraging Aggregations.  Of course, if you're going over the wire, that's still a lot of data to move, so keep that in mind.  Your query will return quickly; the results will take a while to transfer.

The real power of SSAS is being able to be targeted in your approach.  Instead of saying "Give me everything," we can start out at a high level, drill down, find the level we want, and continue drilling down, down, down until you get to the data that you really want.

Comment: Yes, but take things into account like sorting and paging: Assume the end-user on the UI selected one of the rather-top structure nodes, the result are 30'000 articles. Now I want to have them sorted by name and limited to only the first 100 (or 200-300, etc). There isn't really possible anymore..

Comment: Yes it is.  No matter what frontend you use, you can limit the rowset, as well as use the ORDER function in MDX (most frontends have a button for this) to sort them.  I'd argue that Top 10 lists are easier in SSAS than SQL.  That being said, how well do you know MDX?

Comment: Well, the problem with TOP is, it performs bad if you want to grab articles 29'500 to 30'000, using T-SQL you can do all kind of tweaks to only fetch the 'rows page' you really need. How do you deal with that in MDX?
I suck at MDX, that's why I look for opinions like yours.

Comment: You can use the Except to hide the rows above and below a certain index, and sorted however you'd like.  All this being said, do we really need to be paging through 30,000 articles?  I mean, who's going to be doing that?  What information are they really looking for?  Perhaps we can get them a more targeted approach.

Comment: The user will most likely navigate to the leaf nodes of the structure, when only < 100 articles are left, and then start paging through them. However we want to prive the same behavior when displaying the contents of parent/root nodes. Therefore the code must be capable of dealing with that load. So you suggest 'Except'? I'll take a look at this..